# how to sync two remote branches in git?

Tags: git

I just started using git, I am faced with a situation where I have two remote branches *master* and *alpha*.

Each branch has 268 packages.

Now I have to copy everything from branch *master* which had a lot of commits to branch *alpha* which was originally created from branch master.

could any one give me any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you check out alpha.

```
git checkout alpha
```

(do git pull if you are not up to date, or git status to check first)

Then:

If you are the only one that is working on the project, you can use rebase

```
git rebase origin/master
```

If there are other people working on the project, I would suggest to use merge.

```
git merge origin/master
```

Then, you can check your local repo whether everything is good. if it is.
do a commit, then push back to your remote alpha.